# RDS - Dynamic endpoint causing problems with static configuration files

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I'm running into a slight problem with RDS. My system I designed works like so:

- Server A initiates an RDS startup from a snapshot on a daily bases
- Server A puts data in RDS database
- Server A intiates a snapshot of RDS
- Server A shutsdown RDS

The problem is, server A has the RDS endpoint hardcoded into a configuration file but everytime it boots up RDS it's end point changes, with an example URL of this:

```
myname.c9kb7awkert1.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

I can control all the bits of the endpoint apart from this bit: **c9kb7awkert1**

So my question is, how am I meant to cope with this dynamically changing endpoint when I boot up my database each time when all my configurations are static?

Answer (score 1):

RDS isn't really designed for that sort of use case, so you're going to have to do some work on your end. Since server A is creating an RDS instance, you should be able to fetch the endpoint via the AWS APIs you're already using and modify the configuration file.